# Error on omnet++, INET, SIMUlte

Tags: omnet++, inet

I'm doing a vertical handover between wifi and LTE. I created a scenario and now I'm stuck on an error during simulation phase.

```
Error in module (LteMacEnb)
LTEHandovewrNetwork.eNodeB.nic.mac (id=35) at event #40,
t=0.002: std:out_of_range: map::at.
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9RYB.png]

Comment: Could you provide more context to the error?
Like what did you change and where did the error occur. In this case it looks like a very specific error for your scenario.

Comment: actually i am trying to do the vertical handover between 802.11 and LTE.I have created a mobile user which has both wifi card and LTE card.When i run the simulation in omnett++ the error from above will appear after few seconds.I have used omnet++ 4.6 version and inet 2.3.0 and simulte

Comment: Does this also happen if you run a default example? I might be a problem that was introuced in OMNeT++ 4.6 with the UI update.

Comment: no..it works fine with default example...just when i run this program error occurs

Comment: could you please outline more what happens at this event where it crashes. Currently the provided information does not really help to understand the issue